# Excluding one input from .each actions

Tags: jquery-selectors

Given an input defined thusly:

```
<input type="text" id="connectionsCount" />
```

shouldn't this code exclude actions that would otherwise execute.

```
$(".cartOption .value .input").not('#connectionsCount').each(function () {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the other selectors were parents of my #connectionsCount element so i needed to check the children:

.children().not('input:#connectionsCount')

Answer (score 0):

it would invoke on any matched elements that don't match #connectionsCount, so it applies to everything but that.